I can't identify the component if it's a resistor or axial inductor
I have an adapter (12v 2A) which is broken.  i just face that component(indicated by the arrow) and didn't know if it's an axial inductor or a resistor.
I can't find the same colors in any color codes calculator for both inductor or resistor.
What's that component and what's the purpose of it and how to test it with multimeter?

Update( add clean image for the shape and colors)

Do you have an LCR meter? A multimeter would not be able to measure an inductor.

@Hearth i've only a multimeter

Perhaps a "fusible resistor". The answer has a selection of such items. I can't tell from the picture, but could the component in series with the LIVE input to the power supply? If so, could tie in the the location a fusible resistor would be used.

@ChesterGillon yup, there is a wire from the 220v is directly goes to that component, the other one goes to beidge rectifier mb10m

It looks like a cost-cutting bypass of a common-mode choke before the input bridge rectifier (there would need to be another jumper or such like, perhaps on the bottom of the board). The outline on the PCB appears to have 4 pins. They’ve also left out filter components on the output. The empty ‘FU’ position is possibly where a fuse would go if the CM choke was present.
If it measures as a low resistance with your multimeter, its almost certainly okay and you can ignore it. Whatever it is (fusible resistor, inductor or even a fuse). I would expect from the colour code that it is a 1 ohm 5% fusible resistor, and it should be replaced with a similar type if it is open. The extra black band is used by some makers to indicate that it is fusible.
In any case, your root problem is almost certainly the DIP-8 chip. If it has failed short, as they are wont to do, it may have taken out other parts such as a fusible resistor. LCSC has a brief datasheet on the chip but it is not available from them. Replacing just the fusible resistor would simply result in another blown resistor in that case.
Frankly, the cost cutting measures and other subtle indicators do not inspire confidence and you might consider just replacing it with a better quality unit.

You're correct it's 1 ohms 5%. When i mesure it by the multimeter it reads 1. The adapter gives 12V after i replaced the first resistor (1k 5%) but still there is a low current that can't turns a bulb fully. As i'm jus a dev trying to learn new stuffs i'll try harder to see what's the problem. Thanks for the infos

@Hearth I suspect a jumper or solder short under the board, hence the parenthetical comment). Maybe it also bypasses the FU fuse position.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Somehow I missed that.
